# Can't find my Named Credential in Permission Set

Tags: permissions, namedcredentials

I'm trying to give access of my Named Credential to a Profile, but I just can't find the Named Credential on the Available Named Credentials in the Permission Set. I already gave the Permission Set the Read access to the User External Credential object. But I'm still getting the next error when I try to make the callout from my lwc.

`We couldn't access the credential(s). You might not have the required permissions, or the external credential`

Here's my Named Credential
[image]

And The external credential has No Authentication as authentication protocol. (I don't need an authentication protocol because i'm calling an internal api from an lwc, but that's another story)

I can see that in Named Credentials section, my Named Credential is categorized as Secured Endpoint. Is that the problem? I just need to give access of this Named Credential to an specific permission set or profile

Comment: Have you already granted access to the `MMGenerateWorkPlanCredential` external credential in the `External Credential Principal Access` section of your permission set?